# How to use Linq to Sql as a Serial Number Generator to avoid Gaps?

Tags: linq-to-sql

Have created the following Linq to SQL transaction to try and create invoices number without gaps. 
Assuming 2 Tables:

Table 1: InvoiceNumbers. -
Columns ID, SerialNumber, Increment -
Example: 1, 10001, 1

Table 2: Invoices. -
Columns: ID, InvoiceNumber, Name -
Example: 1, 10001, "Bob Smith"

```
        Dim db As New Invoices.InvoicesDataContext
        Dim lastInvoiceNumber = (From n In db.InvoiceNumbers Order By n.LastSerialNumber Descending
                          Select n.LastSerialNumber, n.Increment).First
        Dim nextInvoiceNumber As Integer = lastInvoiceNumber.LastSerialNumber + lastInvoiceNumber.Increment
        Dim newInvoiceNumber = New Invoices.InvoiceNumber With {.LastSerialNumber = nextInvoiceNumber, .Increment = lastInvoiceNumber.Increment}
        Dim newInvoice = New Invoices.Invoice With {.InvoiceNumber = nextInvoiceNumber, .Name = "Test" + nextInvoiceNumber.ToString}
        db.InvoiceNumbers.InsertOnSubmit(newInvoiceNumber)
        db.Invoices.InsertOnSubmit(newInvoice)
    db.SubmitChanges()
```

All works fine but is is possible using this method that 2 users might pick up the same Invoice Number if they hit the transaction at the same time?
If so, is there are better way using Linq to Sql?

Answer (score 0):

Gaps in sequences are **inevitable** when dealing with **transactional** databases.

First, you cannot use `SELECT max(id)+1` because it may give the same `id` to 2 transactions which execute at the same time. This means you have to use database native auto-increment column (MySQL, SQLite) or database sequence (PostgreSQL, MSSQL, Oracle) to obtain next available `id`.

But even using auto-increment sequence does NOT solve this problem.
Imagine that you have 2 database connections that started 2 parallel transactions almost at the same time. First one acquired some `id` from auto-increment sequence and it became previously used value +1. One nanosecond later, second transaction acquired next `id`, which is now +2. Now imagine that first transaction rolled back for some reason (encountered error, your code decided to abort it, program crashed - you name it). After that, second transaction committed with `id` +2, creating a gap in `id` numbering.

But what if number of such parallel transactions was more than 2? You cannot predict, and you also cannot tell currently running transactions to reuse `id`s that were abandoned.

It is theoretically possible to reuse abandoned ids. However, in practice it is prohibitively expensive on database, and creates more problems when multiple sessions try to do the same thing.

**TDLR:** stop fighting it, gaps in used ids are perfectly normal.

Answer (score 0):

You can always assure that the transaction is not running in more than one thread at the same time using lock():

```
private static object myLockObject = new object();
....
....
public class MyClass
{
...
public void TransactionAndStuff()
{
    lock(myLockObject) 
    {
        // your linq query
    }
}
```